# Why getting django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. while creating CustomUser and CustomUserManager

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to run a django application and got an error mentioned in Title.Django 3.2.3 and Python 3.9.5 are used in my project.I got this error when ever trying to run any of the bellow command :-

```
python manage.py makemigrationspython 

manage.py migratepython 

python manage.py runserver
```

**setting.py :-**

```
"""
Django settings for ecommerceproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
import loginsignup.models

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-mw$%fa@7r-g_1*w(d$!bd*si_d3sxrx#c@8i&&(h*@&!(oz#%l'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'products',
    'loginsignup',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerceproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerceproject.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'



# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = loginsignup.models.CustomUsers
```

**Full error:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\ecommerceproject\settings.py", line 17, in <module>
    import loginsignup.models
  File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\ecommerceproject\loginsignup\models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 253, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 136, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

After running django-admin check i got following error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\check.py", line 63, in handle
    self.check(
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 18, in check_all_models
    models = apps.get_models()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 179, in get_models
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 141, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set correct python path to your user model, but not reference the model class object it self. Django needs to initialise properly first.
change
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = loginsignup.models.CustomUsers`
to
`AUTH_USER_MODEL = "loginsignup.models.CustomUsers"`
and remove `import loginsignup.models` from settings.py